# setting background image to a `<body>`

Tags: razor, background, asp.net-core-mvc, background-image

I'm sure it's a simple fix. I just don't see it. I tried the solutions I saw online but neither worked in my case.

**What I'm trying to do:**

set background to my `<body>`

**What my code is doing:**

- blank background for the hello world text in my body.
- only displaying the `<img>` in my `<body>` under my hello world.

---

```
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            background-image: url("~/images/indeximg0.jpg");
            margin:0;
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        hello
        <br>
        world
        <br>
        <img src="~/images/testrootimg.jpg" alt="">
</body>
```

**What I tried:**

**(1)**

- change roots from `url("~/images/indeximg0.jpg")` to  `url("../../wwwroot/images/indeximg0.jpg");`

However my test image after the `<br>` also disappeared

---

**(2)**

- ```
  <body style="background-image: url(~/images/indeximg0.jpg)">
  ```

made no difference

---

**additional information:**

- bootstrap 4.6
- razor framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it help you? This is my testing result

```
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url("/images/bg1.png");
        }
    </style>
```

[image]

By the way, if you're using asp.net core and using _layout in your project, then you wanna set consistent background image for your site, you should set the style in your _Layout.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the image source. If you go on google and find a image and then copy the image address and replace the *~/images/indeximg0.jpg* and *~/images/testrootimg.jpg* with the image address, then it should work and it should look something like this: https://ibb.co/80HsY3Q(hello world is still there, its just in the corner and hard to see)

Comment: It's not a picture from google or one that I find on google. It's an image saved on my computer.

Comment: You could possibly upload your image online to a free hosting platform like I did, then copy the image address of that image.

Comment: Or you could use <img src="/home/USER/Desktop/images/exampleimage.jpeg">  or whatever the file location is to find the image.

Comment: i changed `<body style="background-image: url(~/images/indeximg0.jpg)">` to `<body style="background-image: url(home/Users/jaski/Pictures/LeagueProjectImages/indeximg0.jpg)">` and it still did nothing. the top image already appears. the background one is the one giving me issues

Comment: I think for the background one you need to do background-image: url("example.jpg");

Comment: I think it would more easier for you if you just uploaded the image you want to a free hosting platform and then copy the URL address of that and put that as the body image. ibb.co is a good image hosting platform